# is there any suggestion for this error?

Tags: java, cplex

> Error:(198, 32) java: no suitable method found for addTerm(double,ilog.concert.IloIntVar[]) method ilog.concert.IloLinearIntExpr.addTerm(int,ilog.concert.IloIntVar) is not applicable
>        (argument mismatch; possible lossy conversion from double to int)
>      method ilog.concert.IloLinearIntExpr.addTerm(ilog.concert.IloIntVar,int) is not applicable
>        (argument mismatch; double cannot be converted to ilog.concert.IloIntVar)

```
//for Virtual link Variable Y i,j m,n,k and flow variable F i,j m,n,k

IloIntVar[][][][][] ylink=new IloIntVar[VNVert_k][VNVert_k][VNVert_k][VNVert_k][];
IloIntVar[][][][][] flink=new IloIntVar[VNVert_k][VNVert_k][VNVert_k][VNVert_k][];
for (int i = 0; i < VNVert_k; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < VNVert_k; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < VNVert_k; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < VNVert_k; l++) {
                ylink[i][j][k][l]=cplex.intVarArray(VNVert_k,0,1);
                flink[i][j][k][l]=cplex.intVarArray(VNVert_k,0,1);

            }
        }
    }
}


//---------------------------- Constraints
IloLinearNumExpr exp1 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
IloLinearNumExpr exp2 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
IloLinearNumExpr exp3 = cplex.linearNumExpr();
IloLinearIntExpr exp4 = cplex.linearIntExpr();

for (int i = 0; i <SubVert ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SubVert; j++) {
        //constraint
        exp1.addTerm(M,xlink[i][j]);
        //constraint 5 ∑ Xij=1
        exp2.addTerm(1,xlink[i][j]);
        cplex.addLe(exp2,1);
        // constriant 6 ∑ Xij=1
        exp3.addTerm(1,xlink[i][j]);
        cplex.addEq(exp3,1);
        for (int k = 0; k <SubVert ; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < VNVert_k; l++) {
                //contraint 1
                exp4.addTerm(1.0,flink[i][j][k][l]);
                cplex.addGe(exp1,exp4);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "no suitable method found for addTerm(double,ilog.concert.IloIntVar[])". What do you think this error message means? How do you interpret it?

Comment: for convertion that  i was defined as  IloIntVar    but here inside constraint igives error                                                                                                                 //contraint 1
     exp4.addTerm(1.0,flink[i][j][k][l]);

Comment: That isn't an explanation of your interpretation of that error.

Comment: when ever i want to use ,flink[i][j][k][l]) inside constraint i cant change no suitable method found for addTerm(double,ilog.concert.IloIntVar[])
    method ilog.concert.IloLinearIntExpr.addTerm(int,ilog.concert.IloIntVar) is not applicable   (argument mismatch; possible lossy conversion from double to int)

Comment: instead of using AddTerm can use                                                                          cplex.addGe(exp1, (cplex.sum(flink[i][j][k][l])));                                                          then it will work without error

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message, you are giving `addTerm` a `double` when it wants an `int`.

Comment: @JJThomson That's impossible.

Comment: can i use sum instead of using AddTerm  like this:                                  cplex.addGe(exp1, (cplex.sum(flink[i][j][k][l])));                                               then it will work without error

Comment: I have a feeling that this is the line it's specifically complaining about: `exp4.addTerm(1.0,flink[i][j][k][l]);`

Comment: is there any suggestion for this problem ?

Comment: Try with `1` rather than `1.0`?